I'm trying to make an AoE explosion on my character and the animation loops, but the hitbox only stays for the first loop (I don't want it to loop)
This image shows the animation set that I have made, if there is any questions about transition times then I can supply a list too
using System Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AoESelfDetonate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool CanAoE = true;
    public bool isAoE = false;
    public float AoECoolDown = 5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            Debug.Log("Button Down");

            StartCoroutine(CooldownNoHit());
            
            if (CanAoE == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Can AoE");

                CanAoE = false;
                isAoE = true;
                Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
                anim.SetTrigger("Explode");

                StartCoroutine(ResetAttackCooldown());
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        Debug.Log("On Hit");

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && isAoE == true) 
        { 
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);

            Debug.Log("On Destroy");
        } 
    }

    IEnumerator ResetAttackCooldown()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AoECoolDown);
        CanAoE = true;
    }

    IEnumerator CooldownNoHit()
    {
        isAoE = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.60f);
        isAoE = false;
    }
}

Whenever I press the button that is used to make the animation play, it plays but, it plays forever until I stop the code. It is supposed to be when the button is pressed the animation plays one time and then stops for a few seconds. Also, I want the button I press to be "E" but I don't know how to do that either. The hitbox works correctly and everything it is just the animation. If it is a problem in the unity animator, then can someone try and help me (I'm saying try and help me because I am not supplying images of the animator)
Edit: the Hitbox is not working either

You probably have a transition using the trigger to enter the animation state ... do you have a transition back as well?

@derHugo Yes i have a transition back, i repeated what i did for all my other animations but it still refuses to work, i have tried to fix it but i cant find the problem, if i can send images i willl if it would help.

Animation Clips (.anim) have a Loop property. Here is the documentation that shows it.
If the animation file is part of your avatar (as in not an independent .anim asset file), then go to your import settings for the avatar and under the Animation tab, click the animation in question in the list and you should see the Loop/Loop Time property checked below. If it's an independent asset, just click on the asset and the Inspector should also show the same Loop/Loop Time property. Uncheck it and this will make sure that when the animator state plays, it will play once. Whether it completes the animation, depends on how you set up the state (e.g. Exit times etc).
UPDATE:
You need to reset Triggers to be able to use them again and you also need to set the Idle trigger when you want to leave the Explode state.
For example, adding the following in the ResetAttackCooldown after CanAoE=true; works for me.
Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.ResetTrigger("Explode");
anim.SetTrigger("Idle");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
anim.ResetTrigger("Idle");

I replicated your setup on a cube with Idle having no anim and Explode having a "jumping" anim. Clicked the wheel button on the mouse. And it both Explodes and resets to Idle after the AoECoolDown.

I Have added a picture for the animations, if anyone would like to look i have yet to get a full answer

fwiw, after using a Trigger, you have to reset it. Otherwise it won't trigger again even if you call SetTrigger.

Updated the answer with a working solution.
